# joda Datetime. How to SET timezone to the parsed DateTime?

Tags: scala, playframework, jodatime

I'm using Scala along with play framework. I want to parse the String with simple date and say it's in UTC. So if I have **2018-10-04** I want to get **2018-10-04T00:00:00.000Z**

With this:

```
DateTime.parse("2018-10-04", DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-mm-dd")).withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC)
```

I keep getting **2018-10-03T22:00:00.000Z** if I have +2 timezone. How to just say that it's already in UTC?

Comment: You might want to use java time instead of joda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to use [`LocalDatetime`](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/class-use/LocalDateTime.html) to initially ignore the timezone:

```
scala> LocalDateTime.parse("2018-10-04", DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd"))
res11: org.joda.time.LocalDateTime = 2018-10-04T00:00:00.000
```

then you can use `toDateTime` to make this UTC:

```
scala> LocalDateTime.parse("2018-10-04", DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd")).toDateTime(DateTimeZone.UTC)
res12: org.joda.time.DateTime = 2018-10-04T00:00:00.000Z
```

*Also: You should use MM (month) rather than mm (minute).*

Answer (score 0):

First the imports.

```
import org.joda.time.{DateTime, DateTimeZone}
import org.joda.time.format.DateTimeFormat
```

Since the time part is fixed, we can use a constant suffix for the time part.

```
val timeString = "T00:00:00.000Z"
```

We use string-interpolation to append this to the incoming dates.

```
DateTime.parse(s"2018-10-04$timeString", DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-mm-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ")).withZone(DateTimeZone.UTC)
```